# multiple user sign in using single XMPP connection (use gloox connected to gtalk)

Tags: xmpp, apple-push-notifications, google-talk, gloox

is that possible that multiple user signed in using single XMPP connection?
The purpose is to be able to host gloox on the server to push notification.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, it's not possible in standard XMPP.

You may want to use a xmpp-to-xmpp gateway such as [Spectrum](http://spectrum.im/).